# Multiple rows show in a single row using query in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display the department no. and the number of employees in each department from `EMP` table in a single row. I had one query which display the result in separate rows.

```
select deptno, count(*) from emp
group by deptno;

Dptno Count(*)
10       5
20       3
30       4
```

I want to display the result as a single-row. For example:

```
Dpt10 Count(*) Dpt20 Count(*) Dpt30 Count(*)
10      5        20     3       30     4
```

The output in this forum is not proper but try to understand that the no. 5,3 & 4 should be below `count(*)` column and 10,20 & 30 should be below `deptno`.

Comment: Is the title important? You can return one concatenated string/

Comment: 10 20 30

 5  3  4

is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: 10 5 20 3 30 4 this are i want.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try this -

**Schema**

```
DECLARE @emp TABLE ([deptno] int NULL, [deptcount] int NULL);

INSERT @emp ([deptno], [deptcount]) VALUES (10, 5), (20, 3), (30, 4);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT STUFF((
       SELECT ' ' + CAST([deptno] AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + CAST([deptcount] AS VARCHAR)
       FROM @emp
       FOR XML PATH('')
       ), 1, 1, '')
```

**OutPut**

> 10 5 20 3 30 4

Comment: @SumonBanerjee - here is the syntax of stuff - `STUFF ( < character_expression >, < start >, < length >, 
< character_expression > )`

Answer (score 0):

Since pivot doesn't support several aggregates in SQL Server:

```
with t as (
select 10 id, 15 su union all
select 10 id, 10 su  union all
select 10 id, 5 su  union all
select 20 id, 135 su  union all
select 20 id, 100 su  union all
select 20 id, 15 su  union all
select 30 id, 150 su  union all
select 30 id, 1000 su  union all
select 30 id, 500 su 
)
select max(case when id = 10 then id end) dept10
     , count(case when id = 10 then id end) dept10_cnt
     , max(case when id = 20 then id end) dept20
     , count(case when id = 20 then id end) dept20_cnt
     , max(case when id = 30 then id end) dept30
     , count(case when id = 30 then id end) dept30_cnt
  from t
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/39430)

Comment: can we do this in dynamic way???it's not right to add column in max condition IN CASE IF IT have more number of columns @zaratustrA

Comment: This solution doesn't support a dynamic way. You need to specify all your id values if you want all of them. If you familiar with the Pivot clause, pivot rewrites the query like this with aggregate functions and case in them.

Comment: so if we had to deal with more columns then we can't keep on increasing columns in select statement..if we need to deal with pivot then we can go with dynamic way @zaratustra

Comment: Yes, but you will have your an xml as the result. OP didn't say anything that he needed dynamic way. I wrote this query based on the info OP provided.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, there are several ways that you can convert multiple rows of data into columns.

If you needed to just convert the `count` of each `deptno` into columns, then you could do this easily with either the PIVOT function or a CASE/aggregate combination

```
select 
  sum(case when deptno = 10 then 1 else 0 end) Count_Dpt10,
  sum(case when deptno = 20 then 1 else 0 end) Count_Dpt20,
  sum(case when deptno = 30 then 1 else 0 end) DCount_pt30
from emp
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb751/12)

But part of the problem is that you want to pivot both the `DeptNo` and the `Total_Count` into column - this would need to use 2 different aggregate functions.  In your situation the PIVOT function won't work, so you'd have to use a different aggregate function along with a CASE expression similar to:

```
select 
  max(case when deptno = 10 then deptno end) Dpt10,
  sum(case when deptno = 10 then 1 else 0 end) Count_Dpt10,
  max(case when deptno = 20 then deptno end) Dpt20,
  sum(case when deptno = 20 then 1 else 0 end) Count_Dpt20,
  max(case when deptno = 30 then deptno end) Dpt30,
  sum(case when deptno = 30 then 1 else 0 end) DCount_pt30
from emp;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb751/10/0).  Now since you have unknown departments, so you'll need use dynamic sql.  This will create a sql string that will then be executed.  To create the sql string you'll need to use `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH`.  The dynamic code would be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols 
  = STUFF((SELECT 
             ', max(case when deptno = '+cast(deptno as varchar(10))+' then deptno end) as '+ QUOTENAME('Dpt'+cast(deptno as varchar(10))) 
             + ', sum(case when deptno = '+cast(deptno as varchar(10))+' then 1 else 0 end) as '+ QUOTENAME('Count_Dpt'+cast(deptno as varchar(10))) 
            from emp
            group by deptno
            order by deptno
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
      = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' 
         from emp'

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb751/11/0). this gives you a result:

```
| DPT10 | COUNT_DPT10 | DPT20 | COUNT_DPT20 | DPT30 | COUNT_DPT30 |
|-------|-------------|-------|-------------|-------|-------------|
|    10 |           5 |    20 |           3 |    30 |           4 |
```